# SQL injection of group_key in yii save?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo, yii

I have an feedback form in `yii` which simply takes input and save in `database`. I know yii uses PDO for data save but still it is `SQL vulnerable`.

Controller

```
public function actionFeedback()
{
    $model = new Feedback;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if(isset($_POST['Feedback']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Feedback'];

        if($model->save())
             $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('feedback',array(
                        'model'=>$model,'managerList'=>$managerList,'branchList'=>$branchList,
                ));
        }
```

Model

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('branch, manager,comments', 'required'),
        array('branch,manager', 'length', 'max'=>5),
        array('comments', 'length', 'min'=>10, 'max'=>'2000'),
    );
}
```

View

```
    <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'user-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,       
    )); ?>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'branch'); ?>
         <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'branch', $branchList, array('prompt'=>'Select branch')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'branch'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'manager'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'manager', $managerList, array('prompt'=>'Select manager')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'manager'); ?>
    </div>

 <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'comments'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->extArea($model, 'comments', array('rows'=>15, 'cols'=>75)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'comments'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

For me it is sql injection safe as in save the insert query is like

```
INSERT INTO feedback (branch,manager,comments) VALUES (:yp0,:yp1,:yp2). Bound with :yp0 = '2',:yp1='4',':yp2'='hello this is an testing comments'
```

Still on testing this by third party I saw they inserted a query in this so my system gives error like

> duplicate entry for 4CuJhL8T2Oc1 for key 'group_key'

I searched it an found this error but unable to regenerate it from my front end anyone please suggest how it generated also please provide help to get prevent from this

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It may be best to discuss reproduction steps with the third party.

Comment: a duplicate key violation doesn't mean an sql injection

Comment: @KevinStich thats the problem this is my task. Any way do you know how can i prevent this type vulnerability

Comment: that is not dublicate key violation i have not defined any key/index in my database